# Can we read / update boolean value safely from difference thread?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Can we read / update boolean value safely from difference thread ? I mean is the operation atomic ? I want to know this for all platforms (android, ios, macos, linux, windows)

What i want to do is to use a boolean var as a flag. something like :

```
var isempty: boolean;

::thread x
if not isempty then begin .... isempty := true; end;
...

::thread y
isempty := false:
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about what your proposed code is, and what you mean by "safe". It's so much more complicated than the vague terminology used in the question. For instance, `b := not b` is not atomic on any platform. Is that what you are doing? I don't know, because there's not enough detail.

Comment: i just edited the question :)

Comment: Read about **ABA problem**

Answer (score 4):

That code is not atomic on any platform.

You would need to use one of the atomic intrinsics like `AtomicCmpExchange` or equivalently `TInterlocked.CompareExchange`. Note that these operate on 32 bit or 64 bit operands so you might need to switch to a `LongBool`.

That said, an atomic operation may not be the right solution to your problem. Perhaps the right solution is to use a synchronisation primitive. It's close on impossible for us to judge that given the question. What I am trying to say is that I have just answered the question, "is this atomic". I am absolutely not saying that the solution to you problem is an atomic compare/exchange function.

Comment: no no, i don't want any synchronization, i just want to know if one thread set isempty := xxx then at the exact nanoseconds no other can also set isempty := xxx ? yes about integer i understand the need of AtomicCmpExchange but it's also required for boolean ??

Comment: Sorry, I can't make any sense of that comment.

Comment: ok, sorry david, i updated the question ... hope it's clear now

Comment: I reverted your edit. You changed the question to ask something completely different. It's not fair to change the question after somebody has taken the time to answer it. It renders the answer ridiculous. The answer to that other question is simple though. You don't get tearing on boolean writes on any supported platform.

Comment: Strictly speaking you need an in depth understanding of the hardware platform to use any shared updateable variables between threads before you are qualified to appraise your particular situation.  As a result, David's answer is almost always the safest way to go.  For example, Intel makes quite different promises of unprotected atomicity than ARM and I don't believe that you can even fully assume equivalence between AMD and Intel.  Some situations are easy to understand but this is still often the wrong way to coomunicate